# Changing label text in Form2 after pressing a button in Form1

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, label

How do I change a label text in Form2 after clicking a button in Form1?

For example, I want the label text in Form2 to change to "Button 1 was pressed" if I pressed button1 in Form1 and if i pressed button2 in Form1, it will 
be "Button 2 was pressed".

Note: 
Form1 and Form2 are not shown at the same time. So I would have to click the button and then Form2 will show up with the updated label text.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: please explore before posting question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event click on button1 on your Form1 class

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form= new Form2();
            form.Show();
            // if you want to hide form1
            // this.Hide();
            form.label1.Text = "Hello World";            
        }
```

But before that you should make your label1 marked as public on your Form2.Designer.cs :

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally got it to work as how I wanted it to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this :- 
[C# object of class in different windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902786/c-sharp-object-of-class-in-different-windows-form)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx

[How to access form methods and controls from a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/217389/5096993)

you have to have a reference to the form object in order to access its elements
the elements have to be declared public in order for another class to access them

[Hiding a form and showing another when a button is clicked in a Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4345666/5096993)