# 2 Forms, Make Controls On 2nd Public To 1rst

Tags: c#, forms

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141582/changing-label-text-in-form2-after-pressing-a-button-in-form1).

In order for a button click on form 1 to update a value on form 2, the control on form 2 must be public.  I'm getting this issue in the Form2.Designer.cs where I declare a public control, like:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPrint;
```

But even when I make this appear on the `InitializeComponent()` method, it won't appear and gives the error:

> The variable 'txtPrint' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

However, this control is declared - just not within the `InitializeComponent()` method.  If I try to make the control public in the `InitializeComponent()` method, it throws an error:

> Invalid expression public.

This makes sense, as the `InitializeComponent()` method is private.  Like the linked question, I'm trying to make the controls on form 2 publicly available for updating from form 1.  Like the answer, I would have thought making public controls outside the `InitializeComponent()` method would have allowed this, but it doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Comment: is the control declared at runtime?

Comment: I got it - it's both: declare public outside of `InitializeComponent()` method then inside add the new textbox.  Thanks @NicoRiff

Comment: Use the designer to change the Modifiers property on that control.  Making it public tends to be a code smell though.